# array returned in response object is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, response

I have started using typescript. As part of project, I am using multer and csvtojson npm modules to upload a csv file to application and then return the data from csv file into Mongo Database.

Able to push elements to arrays members and errors i.e., confirmed by console logging the length of array, but array is returning empty in response object

```
//controller to import members 
exports.importMembers = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    uploadFile(req, res);      //Fileupload method is return in below
  } 
  catch (error: any) {
    if(error) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        status_code: 400,
        Error: error
      });
    }
  }
};
```

```
//method to uplaod data
const uploadFile = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    //arrays to store errors occured and members saved from file
    var errors:{}[] = [], members:{}[] = [];
    let filePath : string;

    // multer method
    upload(req, res, (err: any) => {
      if(!(req.file)) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          status_code: 400,
          Message: "Please select file to be imported!",
        })
      } 
      else if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          status_code: 400,
          Info: `Error occurred while uploading file: ${err}`,
        });
      } 
      else {
        filePath = path.join("upload", req.file?.originalname);
        csvtojson().fromFile(filePath).then((source: any) => {
          // Fetching all data from each row and return to member object
          for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) 
          {
             var member = {
               memberEnrollmentID: source[i]["Member Enrollment ID"],
               name: source[i]["Name"],
               dateOfBirth: source[i]["Date Of Birth"],
               IDproofNumber: source[i]["ID Proof Number"],
               email: source[i]["Email"],
               phoneNumber: source[i]["Phone Number"],
               address: source[i]["Address"]
              };
             const newMember = new Members(member);  //saving member to collection
             newMember.save().then((result) => {
               console.log(members.length);    // returning array length
               members.push(result);            // push saved members
             }).catch((error) => {
               console.log(errors.length);      // returning array length
               errors.push(error);              // push errors occured while saving members
             })
          }
          console.log(members.length);    // returning 0
          console.log(errors.length);      // returning 0
          return res.status(200).json({
            status_code: 200,
            Members_Imported : members,  // returning empty array
            Members_Rejected : errors     // returning empty array
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw error; // throw an error to be handled by the calling function
  }
};
```

How could i return the members and errors array with elements stored in a express response object?

Comment: Can you add the output from those log entries? My guess is this `newMember.save().then((...}` is happening asynchronously and the return is happening before it execuites - but the order of logged entries will show if that's the case. If it is. you need an await somewhere

Comment: response is returned only after all the members from file are saved/rejected and I implemented that mechanism by running for loop on length of file columns.
I am assuming it has something to do with scope of array declaration as `members.length` and `errors.length` are returning `zero` outside of for loop, correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Please post the console.log output, in order. If this " newMember.save()" returns a Promise then this "response is returned only after all the members from file are saved/rejected " isn't necessarily true. and then "members.length and errors.length are returning zero" would be because nothing had been added to them yet

Comment: "If this " newMember.save()" returns a Promise" and a quick google says it does. Change it to `await newMember.save()...`

Comment: adding `await` to `newMember.save()` worked. Thank you!